# subprocess call not working

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have this code here

## pifm.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from subprocess import call

def play_old( filename ):
   call(["./pifm ", filename, "88.0", "88307"])
   return

def play_message():
    call(["./WelcomeMessage"])
    return
```

## Run.py

```
#Import
import pifm
import glob, os
import random

#Setup Vars
songs = [""]
randomNum = 0

#Find Music in directory
os.chdir("Music")
for file in glob.glob("*.wav"):
    songs.append(file)

os.chdir("..")
while True:
    randomNum = random.randint(1,len(songs)-1)
    print("Playing Song: " + str(songs[randomNum]))
    pifm.play(str(songs[randomNum]))
    pifm.play_message()
```

It keeps throwing this error every time I run it and I cant figure out why

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 19, in <module>
    pifm.play(str(songs[randomNum]))
  File "/home/pi/PyRate-Radio/pifm.py", line 6, in play
    call(["./pifm ", filename, "88.0", "88307"])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 493, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1259, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

## Any Ideas?

Comment: There is no such `pifm` executable in the parent directory of the `Music` directory; you used `os.chdir('Music')`, then `os.chdir('..')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only passing the file name of the wav file and not including the `Music` directory name.
Also note the change to the call statement, the filename is in a double set of quotes to handle file names with spaces and (obviously) ensure the 2 scripts are executable.

pifm.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from subprocess import call

def play( filename ):
   call("./pifm "+'"'+filename+'"'+" 88.0"+" 88307", shell=True)
   return

def play_message():
    call("./WelcomeMessage")
    return
```

run.py

```
import pifm
import glob, os
import random

#Setup Vars
songs = [""]
randomNum = 0

#Find Music in directory
for file in glob.glob("Music/*.wav"):
    songs.append(file)

while True:
    randomNum = random.randint(1,len(songs)-1)
    print("Playing Song: " + str(songs[randomNum]))
    pifm.play(str(songs[randomNum]))
    pifm.play_message()
```